# PHP alias of specific line in php script?

Tags: php, alias

I am working with levels of security with my app and i have written a function that simply checks - depending on it's session user id what kind of priviligies he/she has. It works fine but in some pages i want to output some information if the user is superuser, and forbid to output information if user is a guest.

I do it with such a syntax:

```
1. <? if admin('superuser', $_SESSION['user_id'])  { ?>
2. <div></div>
3. <? } ?>
```

It works good but it's not elegant, and in case long code between curling brackets it messess with purity of my code.
Is there a way to "alias" a line 1 and 3 to some kind of shortcut, ie

```
1. <? admin_superuser ?>
2. <div></div>
3. <? admin_super_user_end ?>
```

Maybe you have some other ideas to perform such levels of security?

The idea came from ob_start() and ob_end() commands. 
I am waiting for your ideas.

Kalreg.

Comment: I think your headache would be solved by not throwing your html inline with your php. Templating engines have solved these problems already. Keep your logic in php and your html in a template.

Comment: You can see PHP as a template engine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could simply set a bool at the beginning of the page:

```
$isSuperUser = admin('superuser', $_SESSION['user_id']);
```

Then, just do

```
<? if ($isSuperUser) { ?>
<div></div>
<? } ?>
```

If you don't like the $, you could define a constant:

```
define("SUPERUSER", admin('superuser', $_SESSION['user_id']));
```

Then, just do

```
<? if (SUPERUSER) { ?>
<div></div>
<? } ?>
```

Good thing about a constant is that it is global, and if using in a function, you wouldn't have to declare it global first, or pass it as an argument.

Comment: Seems practical at first, but it conveys uncontrolled growth in bigger projects. Keep it controllable; always know where you can get something, and not just some other super global thingy which floats around everywhere. My 2 cents...

Answer (score 3):

I would go with something like this. I think this totally acceptable.
To simplify it you just need a wrapper for your user.

```
<?php if ($user->isAdmin()): ?>
<div></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Encapsulation would be the best choice imo too, if the author is comfortable with OOP

Answer (score 2):

you can include another php file that contains the corresponding html / php code with the "include" function. i also recommend to use `<?php` instead of just `<?` due short open tag issues with xml and ini settings.